# memory issue when merging two data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck at this second last statement clueless. The error is : numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 58.1 GiB for an array with shape (7791676634,) and data type int64

My thinking was that merging a data frame of ~12 million records with another data frame of 3-4 more columns should not be a big deal.
Please help me out. Totally stuck here. Thanks

Select_Emp_df has around 900k records
and Big_df has around 12 million records and 9 columns. I just need to merge two DFs like we do vlookup in Excel on key column.

```
import pandas as pd

Emp_df = pd.read_csv('New_Employee_df.csv', low_memory = False )

# Append data into one data frame from three csv files of 3 years' 
transactions
df2019 = pd.read_csv('U21_02767G - Customer Trade Info2019.csv', 
low_memory = False )
df2021 = pd.read_csv('U21_02767G - Customer Trade 
Info2021(TillSep).csv', low_memory = False)
df2020 = pd.read_csv('Newdf2020.csv', low_memory = False)

Big_df = pd.concat([df2019, df2020, df2021], ignore_index=True)

Select_Emp_df = Emp_df[['CUSTKEY','GCIF_GENDER_DSC','SEX']]

Big_df = pd.merge(Big_df, Select_Emp_df, on='CUSTKEY')
print (Big_df.info)
```

Comment: `concat` and `merge` copies values to a new dataframe by default, so it seems like you ran out of a free memory block large enough to write the new dataframes. You could try writing the argument `copy=False`, but that's not a guarantee. Oftentimes copying happens anyways because there's not enough free trailing memory to do in-place append and viewing.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Thanks I tried it but it did not work!

Comment: Well judging from the other tips not working, you may just be working with too large datasets for your available RAM. In that case, you would have to load a smaller portion of the data from the disk into RAM at a time. The Pandas docs have some tips (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html), but at the end they suggest Dask dataframes for a pandas-like API that loads portions into RAM as Pandas dataframes (https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before  `Big_df = pd.merge(Big_df, Select_Emp_df, on='CUSTKEY')` 
try to delete previous dataframes. Like this.

```
del df2019
del df2020
del df2021
```

This should save some memory

also try

```
Select_Emp_df = Emp_df[['CUSTKEY','GCIF_GENDER_DSC','SEX']].drop_duplicates(subset=['CUSTKEY'])
```

Comment: you can save memory by changing the datatypes of the dataframe. can you share a sample of the dataframe? Also are you sure Select_Emp_df only has unique values?

Comment: 'Drop duplicates' property worked for me when I selected just 3 columns but as soon as I selected more columns it is not working. Same error.

`Select_Emp_df = Emp_df[['CUSTKEY','DTBIRTH','GCIF_GENDER_DSC','SEX','GCIF_RACE_DESC','OCCPSEC_DS','EMPLYMTSEC_DESC', 'GCIF_MTHICM_DSC', 'DTACCTOPEN','LSTTRDDT']].drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Hi Sample here in two different tabs. Thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RMsulgwDgV2dN2GX6W7za8cNM5iJKJPq/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104878018080513169323&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: can you use this for merging. You might have duplicates in Emp_df  `Big_df = pd.merge(Big_df, Select_Emp_df, on='CUSTKEY', validate='many_to_one')`

Comment: I tried checking for duplicates first using - 
`boolean = Select_Emp_df.duplicated().any()
print(boolean, end='\n\n') `

This resulted in False output. then I tried your suggestion - `Big_df = pd.merge(Big_df, Select_Emp_df, on='CUSTKEY', validate='many_to_one')`
But this resulted in error - pandas.errors.MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in right dataset; not a many-to-one merge

Answer (score 1):

When younger, I used machines where available RAM per process where 32k to 640k. And I used to process huge datasets on that (err... several Mo but much larger than memory). The key was to only keep in memory what was required.

Here you concat 3 large dataframes to later merge that with another one. If you have memory issues, just reverse concat and merging: merge each individual file with `Emp_df` and immediately write the merged file to the disk an throw everything out of your memory between each step. If you use csv files, you can even directly build the contatenated csv file by appending the 2nd and 3rd merge files to the first one (use `mode='a', header=False` in `to_csv` method).

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestions provided by community here and a bit of my research I edited my codes and here is what worked for me -

`Select_Emp_df['LSTTRDDT'] = pd.to_datetime(Select_Emp_df['LSTTRDDT'],errors = 'coerce') Select_Emp_df = Select_Emp_df.sort_values(by='LSTTRDDT',ascending=True) Select_Emp_df = Select_Emp_df.drop_duplicates(subset='CUSTKEY',keep='last')`

I just sorted values on Last transaction date and deleted duplicates(IN CUSTKEY) in `Select_Emp_df` data frame.